# VS 2015 Locals, Autos, Watch windows are empty for some views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have asp.net mcv project, suddenly Locals and Autos windows became empty and in Watch window began to return - Unable to evaluate the expression. This happens only on some specific views...I've tried to check debugger settings, but I have not idea where to dig,because it's not occurs on all views..
[image: issue]
Any ideas will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I've just started running into this problem with VS 2015 Update 1. Let me know if you resolved this somehow, please.